# How do I refer to "global" variables & objects from deep inside an openGL application?

Tags: opengl, static, size, viewport, dimensions

I'm writing an object oriented openGL application, which renders some 3D models (which are stored in my own classes with several attributes and methods). One of these object types (with volume rendering shader) require that I render the output to a fixed size texture first (say 256*256), then restore the previous viewport size and stretch this texture over the screen in 2D.

The actual problem is that I can't get the actual viewport size from inside this object, unless (I guess) I store a reference to the GLEventListener's GLU object, which I obviously don't want for each and every model I create.

But I also don't want to have static variables in the GLEventListener (what if I want an app which has 2 canvases?)

The most important is the viewport dimensions, but I think I'll also need to reference my custom Camera object. How can I do this without using *static* somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please read http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem

Next I point you to the function [`glGetIntegerv`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) on the token GL_VIEWPORT.

Comment: Thank you! glGetIntegerv is apparently what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the viewport information and any other data that wouldn't change per canvas (etc) in a single struct, and then just store a single pointer with each object

Comment: but that's the point, I really don't want to store a pointer in each and every object (you mean, like pass it in the constructor?)

Comment: If you want to have objects rendering to different canvases then you're going to need to store it somewhere.